# Dealing with multiple boolean state variables for validation

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I'm building a form in React, and have a function to validate the email and password as provided by the user: if either do not pass validation, a state variable is flipped from true to false, and an error message is conditionally rendered:

***State variables***

```
const [isEmail, setEmail] = useState(true);
const [isPassword, setPassword] = useState(true);
```

***Validation function***

```
  const validateEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
    const emailRegEx =
      /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]****************;
    email.match(emailRegEx) ? setEmail(true) : setEmail(false);
    password.length > 8 ? setPassword(true) : setPassword(false);
  };
```

***Error message***

```
<p className="errors">{!isEmail ? errors.email : null}</p>
```

Instead of declaring each state variable individually, what would be the best way to declare them toegther, as I've done with the other inputs in my form?

Here's the complete file:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Form = () => {
  const [{ email, password,colour }, setFormDetails] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    colour: ""
  });
  const [isEmail, setEmail] = useState(true);
  const [isPassword, setPassword] = useState(true);
  const [isTigerChecked, setTigerChecked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = 'Contact form'
},[])


  const errors = {
    password: "Password needs to contain 8 or more characters",
    email: "Please enter a valid email",
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormDetails((prevForm) => ({
      ...prevForm,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const validateEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
    const emailRegEx =
      /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    email.match(emailRegEx) ? setEmail(true) : setEmail(false);
    password.length > 8 ? setPassword(true) : setPassword(false);
  };
  
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.target.checked ? setTigerChecked(true) : setTigerChecked(false)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <p>Contact form</p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          className="form-element"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter email address"
          name="email"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <p className="errors">{!isEmail ? errors.email : null}</p>
        <input
          className="form-element"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          name="password"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <p className="errors">{!isPassword ? errors.password : null}</p>
        <fieldset className="form-element">
          <legend>Please select a colour</legend>
          <select name="colour" id="colour" onChange = {handleChange}>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Black">Black</option>
            <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
          </select>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset className="form-element">
          <legend>Please select your animals</legend>
          <div className="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bear" name="bear"  />
            <label for="bear"> Bear</label>
            <br></br>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="Tiger"
              name="Tiger"
              onClick={handleClick}
            />
            <label for="Tiger"> Tiger</label>
            <br></br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Snake" name="Snake" />
            <label for="Snake"> Snake</label>
            <br></br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Donkey" name="Donkey" />
            <label for="Donkey"> Donkey</label>
            <br></br>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        {isTigerChecked ? (
          <textarea
            id="tiger-type"
            name="tiger-type"
            rows="4"
            cols="50"
            placeholder="Please enter type of Tiger"
          />
        ) : null}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:
Get rid of the isEmail and isPassword states, and make an errors state with an empty object as the initial value.

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
```

and change the name of the errors obj that holds the error messages to errorMessages

```
const errorMessages = {
    password: "Password needs to contain 8 or more characters",
    email: "Please enter a valid email",
}
```

Within your validate function, make an errorsObj variable assigned to an empty object. If email doesn't match, update the errorsObj so that the email key is assigned to the email error string from your errors object (same for password).

```
const errorsObj = {};
if(!email.match(emailRegEx)) errorsObj['email'] = errors['email']
if (!(password.length > 8)) errorsObj['password'] = errors['password']
setErrors(errorsObj);
```

now when conditionally rendering the error messages, do this

```
{!!errors['email'] && <p className="errors">{errors['email'}</p>}
{!!errors['password'] && <p className="errors">{errors['password'}</p>}
```

you could also adjust your handleChange function to update errors properly

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormDetails((prevForm) => ({
      ...prevForm,
      [name]: value,
    }));
    if (errors[name]) {
        setErrors(prevState => {
            delete prevState[name];
            return prevState;
        }
    }
  };
```